# while running Selenium getting broken UI in webpage python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping, webdriverwait

having trouble with selenium. Trying to parse one webpage and while running it Im having broken UI, therefore couldn't fill fields with text(getting error not interactable)
[image]

how it looks in general
what i have after running selenium

[image]

> Message: element not interactable   (Session info:
> chrome=99.0.4844.84) Stacktrace: Backtrace:   Ordinal0
> [0x00BF9943+2595139]  Ordinal0 [0x00B8C9F1+2148849]   Ordinal0
> [0x00A843F0+1065968]  Ordinal0 [0x00AAC4D3+1230035]   Ordinal0
> [0x00AABB8B+1227659]  Ordinal0 [0x00ACB9EC+1358316]   Ordinal0
> [0x00AA7474+1209460]  Ordinal0 [0x00ACBC04+1358852]   Ordinal0
> [0x00ADBAF2+1424114]  Ordinal0 [0x00ACB806+1357830]   Ordinal0
> [0x00AA6086+1204358]  Ordinal0 [0x00AA6F96+1208214]   GetHandleVerifier
> [0x00D9B232+1658114]  GetHandleVerifier [0x00E5312C+2411516]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x00C8F261+560433]   GetHandleVerifier
> [0x00C8E366+556598]   Ordinal0 [0x00B9286B+2173035]   Ordinal0
> [0x00B975F8+2192888]  Ordinal0 [0x00B976E5+2193125]   Ordinal0
> [0x00BA11FC+2232828]  BaseThreadInitThunk [0x773EFA29+25]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77AA7A7E+286]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77AA7A4E+238]

my code:

```
url = "https://opi.dfo.kz/p/ru/archive-publication/corporative-events-2020-14-07"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CorporativeEvents20201407"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]')
element.send_keys('010140000143')
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send text directly to that element.
You should click on that element, this will open another `input` element where you will be able to insert your text input.
Also you have to use Expected Conditions explicit waits here.
This works:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = "https://opi.dfo.kz/p/ru/archive-publication/corporative-events-2020-14-07"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CorporativeEvents20201407"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='editor-text tip']"))).send_keys("010140000143")
```

The `'//*[@id="CorporativeEvents20201407"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]'` XPath locator can and should be improved as well. You can use `//div[@class='logic-group-condition' and .//span[@field-name='tbOpiActiveRevisions_flBin']]` Instead. This locator is much more reliable. So your code will be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = "https://opi.dfo.kz/p/ru/archive-publication/corporative-events-2020-14-07"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='logic-group-condition' and .//span[@field-name='tbOpiActiveRevisions_flBin']]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='editor-text tip']"))).send_keys("010140000143")
```

This is the screen shot of the web page after applying my code:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I get it that I should click on element and opent another input. but can u explain how it worked on ur computer? I have the same problem with broken UI after 20 secs it throws me TimeoutException.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. This code works correctly on my computer. It opens the input field and fills it with text.

Comment: See the screen shot

Comment: thanks a lot. When I running it, my webpage is broken, still UI issue

Comment: In case you still have some problem - please open a new question, I will try helping again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635577/while-running-selenium-on-windows-having-ussue-with-webpage-uisome-forms-are-b