# Webpage UI elements and forms are broken while interacting using expected_conditions as visibility_of_element_located() using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, webdriverwait, expected-condition

Having issue with selenium, while running my test chrome page are broken(some forms are broken, fields not in correct position, therefore cant fill data on it)

Should open like this
[image]

But have this:
[image]

In case have similar version of chromedriver and chrome:

```
current google-chrome version is 99.0.4844
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 99.0.4844 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\yerba\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\99.0.4844.51\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://opi.dfo.kz/p/ru/archive-publication/corporative-events-2020-14-07"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='logic-group-condition' and .//span[@field-name='tbOpiActiveRevisions_flBin']]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='editor-text']"))).send_keys("010140000143")
```

Comment: I can't see how your page UI becomes broken. With my selenium script it looks correct

Answer (score 0):

As per the Selenium Python API docs [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. However, this condition doesn't garuntees that the element is ***clickable*** and ***interactable***.

---

### Solution

Ideally, to invoke *`click()`* and *`send_keys()`* instead of [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='logic-group-condition' and .//span[@field-name='tbOpiActiveRevisions_flBin']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='editor-text']"))).send_keys("010140000143")
```